# How to speed up complex ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables: `translationKeys`, `translationSuggestions` and `translationComments`, `translationSuggestionActivities`. Each one contains a `created`column.

My query (simplified) looks like this:

```sql
SELECT 
a.created, 
c.created, 
s.created
FROM translationKeys k
JOIN translationSuggestions s ON k.id = s.translationKeyId
LEFT JOIN translationComments c ON c.translationSuggestionId = s.id
LEFT JOIN translationSuggestionActivities a ON a.translationSuggestionId = s.id

WHERE k.gameId = 11

ORDER BY a.created DESC, c.created DESC, s.created DESC
LIMIT 20
```

My execution plan looks like this (apologize for the messy index names):
[image: Execution Plan]

Execution time is around 400ms. If I remove `ORDER BY created DESC` the execution time instantly drops to 10ms. I understand this is because the ordering is happening in a temp table.

I've tried setting up indexes for each table including the `created` column and all referred columns, but with no difference.

My question is: Is it possible to improve the performance of this sorting or am I trying to accomplish something impossible?

Comment: You can ask this question on the [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) site of the network

Comment: How vital is it that the ordering is by created and not by the IDs? If your tables have auto-incrementing IDs, their ordering should be mostly identical to created timestamps and they'll be unique keys, giving the optimizer a better handle on how many rows will be returned.

Comment: It's not vital.I just want the newest rows, but wouldn't it require that all 3 tables auto-increment the IDs together?

Answer (score 0):

Since the ORDER BY column is made of a COALESCE of different tables and columns, you won't be able to fix this with any index.

However you're just selecting 20 rows. Why don't you simply sort the result in your code?

Comment: I just tested and removing COALESCE didn't change the execution plan. I have updated the query above to a more simple version. 

I'm using the query for pagination which is why I need a LIMIT.

Comment: I see, but the thing is, MySQL will only use one index per table. You'd have to use a combined index on the column you're joining on and the column you're ordering by. Even then MySQL most of the time chooses to only use the index for joining, not for ordering. Don't ask me why. But in this case here, since you're ordering by 3 different tables anyway, you can do whatever you want, you won't bring MySQL to avoid the temporary table. Sorting in code is the best thing you can do here.

Comment: My problem is that I have millions of rows, so the fetching time will exceed the execution time, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

AS long as translationKeys in InnerJoined with other tables, therefore you might better order and sort and where in the master table(translationKeys) then apply left joins. Maybe This would be helpful (check the 2 results):

```
;with tempTable as (
   SELECT *  //Or your needed columns
     FROM translationKeys
      WHERE translationKeys.gameId = 11
  )

SELECT 
 COALESCE(translationSuggestionActivities.created, translationComments.created, 
 translationSuggestions.created) as created
 FROM tempTable 
 INNER JOIN translationSuggestions ON tempTable.id = 
 translationSuggestions.translationKeyId
LEFT JOIN translationComments ON translationComments.translationSuggestionId = 
translationSuggestions.id
LEFT JOIN translationSuggestionActivities ON 
 translationSuggestionActivities.translationSuggestionId = 
   translationSuggestions.id
     ORDER BY created DESC
             LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I believe this would only sort by `translationKeys.created`. I need the 20 newest rows based on the `created` column from all 3 tables.

Comment: anyway, I think it might be better to fuse CTE to set WHERE clause in it. then do the rest of joins

Answer (score 0):

The only improvement I can think is to switch to `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`.  I'm not 100% sure this meets your needs, but you are sorting by columns in the `LEFT JOIN`ed tables, so the `NULL` values are last anyway:

```
SELECT a.created, c.created, s.created
FROM translationKeys k JOIN
     translationSuggestions s
     ON k.id = s.translationKeyId JOIN
     translationComments c
     ON c.translationSuggestionId = s.id JOIN
     translationSuggestionActivities a
     ON a.translationSuggestionId = s.id
WHERE k.gameId = 11
ORDER BY a.created DESC, c.created DESC, s.created DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

This should reduce the number of rows returned and slightly improve the performance of the `ORDER BY`.

That said, the ordering is combining columns from different tables, so you cannot improve performance with an index.